# How increase GStreamer Buffer size during video streaming?

Tags: opencv, streaming, buffer, gstreamer

I'm using below opencv and gstreamer codes to send and receive a video over network. In receiver side I'm getting distorted video and a warning message "Redistribute latency and not enough buffering available for the processing deadline, add enough queues to buffer". I tried 'queue max-size-bytes=900000 max-size-buffer=0 max-size-time=0' but no luck. I'm in windows environment. Any ways to improve the buffer?

**Sender**

cv::VideoWriter m_videoOut("appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.200 port=5000 sync=false", cv::CAP_GSTREAMER, 0 , 30, cv::Size(640,480),true);

**Receiver**

cv::VideoCapture cap("udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H264, payload=96 ! rtph264depay queue-delay=0 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! appsink", cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);